# ORACLE: ORA-06550 Error at "Select into"

Tags: oracle, ora-06550

I get error ORA-06550 on the SELECT INTO line when executing following SQL:

```
DECLARE 
  new_type INTEGER;
  cur_idCardProfileId DECIMAL;

  CURSOR IDCardProfileCursor
   IS
    SELECT idcardprofileid FROM idcard;    
BEGIN
  FOR cur_idCardProfileId IN IDCardProfileCursor
  LOOP
    SELECT cardtype INTO new_type FROM idcardprofile WHERE idcardprofileid = cur_idCardProfileId;
  END LOOP;        
END;
```

Both idcardprofileid (table 'idcard') and idcardprofileid (table 'idcardprofile') are of type DECIMAL.

I got no clue anymore... Thank you in advance.

Comment: `ORA-06550` doesn't usually tell you much on it's own. It's more useful to show the whole exception stack, which in this case would include `PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type`, which is rather more helpful. You seem to have seen that and realised it was important as you mentioned the `DECIMAL` type, but showing us would be good too *8-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're referring to the cursor row incorrectly. Your cursor row is being named `cur_idCardProfileId`, which takes precedence over the `DECIMAL` value you've declared with the same name; that is not used at all here.

When you refer to the value from the cursor you need to use the column name as well as the row variable name. Using a shorter name `cur` and with a table alias to avoid ambiguity you could do:

```
DECLARE 
  new_type INTEGER;

  CURSOR IDCardProfileCursor
   IS
    SELECT idcardprofileid FROM idcard;    
BEGIN
  FOR cur IN IDCardProfileCursor
  LOOP
    SELECT cardtype INTO new_type
    FROM idcardprofile i
    WHERE i.idcardprofileid = cur.idcardprofileid;
  END LOOP;        
END;
/
```

Of course you wouldn't normally do a select inside a loop like this, you'd have the cursor joining the two tables as that's more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The ORA-06550, is a compilation error occuring in case of incorrect syntax, usually the line no and the reason for error are mentioned in the message.

Coming to your question:

There are couple of syntax errors in your annonymous block:

a.) You do not need to declare cur_idCardProfileId
b.) When you refer a column returned by a cursor set you need to use `<loop_variable>.column_name` notation, so the `Select Into` should be having  `cur_idCardProfileId.idcardprofileid`

Have made changes in your block, the modified block is given below:

```
     DECLARE 
      new_type INTEGER;
    --  cur_idCardProfileId DECIMAL;

     CURSOR IDCardProfileCursor
     IS
     SELECT idcardprofileid FROM idcard;    
      BEGIN
        FOR cur_idCardProfileId IN IDCardProfileCursor
        LOOP
          SELECT cardtype 
          INTO new_type 
          FROM idcardprofile 
          WHERE idcardprofileid = cur_idCardProfileId.idcardprofileid; --Replaced   cur_idCardProfileId with cur_idCardProfileId.idcardprofileid
    END LOOP;        
    END;
```

Hope it Helps

Vishad

Comment: Could you explain how this is different _why_ it answers the question?